# CDH5 hdfs balancer error

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

running 'hdfs balancer', i do see it showing the rack topology installed, over-utilized and underutilized nodes, it says "Need to move 5 TB to make the cluster balanced" and "Decided to move 10 GB bytes from 10.150.11.24:50010 to 10.150.11.164:50010"

then i see this error,

> WARN balancer.Balancer: Dispatcher thread failed
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.balancer.Balancer.isGoodBlockCandidate(Balancer.java:1233)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.balancer.Balancer.access$400(Balancer.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.balancer.Balancer$Source.isGoodBlockCandidate(Balancer.java:686)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.balancer.Balancer$Source.getBlockList(Balancer.java:674)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.balancer.Balancer$Source.dispatchBlocks(Balancer.java:776)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.balancer.Balancer$Source.access$1600(Balancer.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.balancer.Balancer$Source$BlockMoveDispatcher.run(Balancer.java:614)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

then this,

> No block has been moved for 5 iterations. Exiting...
>
> WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException):
>   No lease on /system/balancer.id: File does not exist. Holder
>   DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-201468433_1 does not have any open files.     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:2937)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.analyzeFileState(FSNamesystem.java:2757)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2665)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:569)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:440)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)

and namenode log would show this,

> WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:
>   PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs (auth:SIMPLE)
>   cause:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException: No
>   lease on /system/balancer.id: File does not exist. Holder
>   DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-201468433_1 does not have any open files.
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 118 on 8020,
>   call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from
>   10.150.11.126:56490 Call#71 Retry#0: error: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException: No lease
>   on /system/balancer.id: File does not exist. Holder
>   DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-201468433_1 does not have any open files.

i searched and found some discussion regarding duplicate balancer processes but i could not find this issue in our cluster.  anyone have other ideas?  we are using cdh5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In CDH you should have a node which is running the HDFS balancer service. That is preventing the hdfs balancer from the command line.

See here:

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/Running-HDFS-Balancer-fail-report-namenode-LeaseExpiredException/td-p/14052